# Mvvmcross PictureChooser Plugin - Droid - Picture orientation is wrong

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using the following code to choose a photo on both iOS and Droid; however, on Droid, images taken in portrait are saved in landscape orientation. On iOS, the image saves with the correct orientation.

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPictureChooserTask>().TakePicture(2000, 64, CaptureImageStream, () =>
{
    /* don't do anything on cancel */
});

protected virtual void CaptureImageStream(Stream stream)
{
    var fileStore = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStore>();
    const string folderName = "Observation_Photos";
    fileStore.EnsureFolderExists(folderName);

    //get file name
    var fileName = RandomString(10);
    while (fileStore.Exists(string.Format("{0}/{1}.jpg", folderName, fileName)))
    {
        fileName = RandomString(10);
    }

    //get file bytes
    var fileContents = GetBytes(stream);

    //write file
    var fullPath = string.Format("{0}/{1}.jpg", folderName, fileName);
    fileStore.WriteFile(fullPath, fileContents);
}

private static IEnumerable<byte> GetBytes(Stream stream)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the photo has the wrong orientation on droid or how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Maybe try this recent PullRequest - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/627

Comment: I failed to mention that I am on 3.0.14. I used the version of the MvxPictureChooserTask.cs that you linked to, and that fixed the problem. I'm not sure if you want that to be the official answer or not though...

Comment: Hi @ZachGreen , could you share your solution for this? are you injecting a service in ? and are you using the picturechoser.droid library? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AhmedW The most current version of the plugin fixed it for me. I don't have any custom code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update version of the MvxPictureChooserTask.cs from this pull request, https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/627, fixed the problem.